# AVPlayer only plays in simulator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, avplayer

I am downloading an MP3 file using `NSURLConnection` and I save the data to a file using `NSFileHandle`. Whenever a certain percentage of the file is downloaded (all the files are roughly the same size), I will start playing the MP3 file.

I thought that I could use the `AVPlayer` to do this but it doesn't work on a device - only in simulator.

I do the following:

```
if (self.player.rate == 0.0f && percentage > kMinimumDownloadPercentage)
{
    NSError *error;
    self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:[[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:localPath]];
    if (!error)
        [self.player play];
    else
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
}
```

This works in simulator but not on device. No error is given. It does work if I do the following, though:

`self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];`

Where `url` is the remote URL to the MP3 file.

Does anyone know why I can't play the local file using `AVPlayer`?

Comment: Comparison of floating-point values using `==` looks scary.

Comment: That's true. I have corrected this. Should anyone be interested, here is a great post on how to avoid using the `==` operator. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1614761/486845.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be an error due to the way the file was saved.

`-playerWithURL:` in `AVPlayer` works **perfectly fine**.

Comment: I am having similar issues, what was the error (the way the file was saved), I think I just might be having the same error @simonbs